# AS3: Extending The Dictionary Class - Accessing Stored Data

Tags: actionscript, dictionary, extension-methods

So I want to extend the dictionary class. Everything works so far except that in some of my methods that need to reference the dictionary's content I make a call like:

```
this[ key ]
```

It doesn't like that. It just tells me that there's no property 'key'.  Is there a way to way to access the data within this class?

Also, I'm using an integer for the key.

**Edit:** I've found that the same behavior happens when you extend Array.

```
var myArray : Array = new Array();
trace( myArray[ 0 ] );
var myArrayExtender : ArrayExtender = new ArrayExtender();
trace( myArrayExtender[ 0 ] );
```

Where in this case, myArray returns "undefined" and myArrayExtender throws error 1069. ArrayExtender is an empty class that extends Array and calls super() in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you say, i am quite sure you did not declare `ArrayExtender` as `dynamic`
in ECMAscript array access and property access are semantically equivalent ... #1069 happens, if you access an undefined property, on a [**sealed** class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript_tips.html), because thes do not allow adding properties at runtime ...

same thing for the `Dictionary` ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Interesting. Helpful again. Thank you sir or madam.